How to fetch postgresql with pg-query-stream from server side?
I might be close, but not quite there yet as the below throws Error: Invalid response from route /api: handler should return a Response object, probably I do return just an object and not a Response?
routes/api/+server.ts
/** @type {import('./$types').RequestHandler} */
export async function GET({ url }) { 

...

 var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
     pool.connect(async (err, client, done) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        const query = new QueryStream(querystring)
        const stream = client.query(query);
        stream.on('end', done)
        return stream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res)
     })
  })

  return server;

}

src/lib/api.js
async function getDatabaseData (/** @type {string} */ url) {
    // fetch internal server api.
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
    });
    let d = await response.json();
    return d.message;
}

I assume returning 'server' is all wrong, but this is just my another attempt. Appreciate an heads up, thank you
Edit: with the code in the post below, I am now getting data correctly on the server side, but still facing the issue of streaming it to the client via a 'stringified' Response. How do I measure progress while streaming a postgres database query via pg-query-stream?

Do you need the http.createServer wrapper? I'm able to get your example working in mine without it, but I'm using the node-adapter with SvelteKit.

actually no, I don't need that wrapper. I am also using the node adapter. Appreciate your advice
